# issues in exe files from bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, iexpress

ok...Im a new member here and I can express how jolly I am...back to subject

I made a bat file, lets call it `1.bat` and I used iexpress to make it an exe file, lets call it `1.exe`.

So, in the batch file I added the command line to add a vbs file ( call it `1.vbs` ) which is also included in the exe package (`1.bat` and `1.vbs` are in `1.exe`) but it installs `1.bat`, so in the command I typed:

```
copy "1.vbs" "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"
```

If I run the bat file it copies the vbs file to start up, but if I make the `1.exe` file in iexpress by including `1.bat` and `1.vbs` and when I click the `1.exe` file, it doesnt work, it doesn't copy the vbs file to startup, it says something about too many parameters.

I'm sorry if my post is too long or my question have been posted before, but I couldn't found any thread solves my issues, if there is, i'd be glad to be enlightened.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Never use "Batch to EXE" converter, they often do not work as expected. Simply use the batch script.

> Just a note, this file actually only acts as a wrapper for your script, and the script itself actually gets executed in a temp folder created on execution (and deleted afterwards), so make sure you don't use any relative paths.

[source](https://superuser.com/a/868341)

Answer (score 0):

When running a batch file in IExpress, you need to call it like:

```
cmd /c 1.bat
```

If you don’t, variables like `%username%`, long file names, etc, will likely not work.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you are using short file names. Put in your bat dir then pause and you'll see it's 1~1.vbs or similar.